# is there anyway to add a song to an existing specific playlist from my ipod touch

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, playlist

If I am listening to all my music and I hear a song and I think it would be great to add to a certain playlist (lets say a playlist i called "gym mix", is there anyway to do this from the iPod touch itself, instead of having to remember this and them do it from iTunes when i am at my computer.  This seems like a basic function but i can't find it anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're running the latest iOS:

Select a playlist. Select "Edit" from the buttons at the top of the playlist under the search field. Tap the "+" in the top left of the toolbar. Find the song(s) you want, and hit the "+" to the right of their name. Tap "Done" when finished.

Comment: thanks this does seem to work to add songs to playlists from ipod touch but its far from the one click "Add to playlist" right when i am listening to a particular song

Comment: The old On-the-go playlist functionality isn't available on iOS- there's no one-click/tap/hold solution I'm afraid.

Comment: There is no shorter way of doing it that that described by Gauzy.  As your original question was one of possibility that speed, I would suggest you accept his answer, as it seems to be correct for the original post.